# fulfilling nested interfaces in golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, interface

I have an Interface that has a lot of submethods.

```
type InterfaceCheckout interface {
    GetID()    int
    GetItems() []InterfaceCartItem
    // ... then like 30more methods
}
```

I have a method that only makes use of the GetItems method.

```
func GetRates(checkoutI InterfaceCheckout) []Rate {
    for _, item := range checkoutI.GetItesm() {
        p := item.GetProduct()
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to test this `GetRates` method without mocking all of the methods in `InterfaceCheckout`.

I thought I'd be able to:

1. create some smaller interfaces that specify only the methods I'm making use of
2. cast the input as this new interface
3. pass through to a new internal method

   ```
   func GetRates(checkoutI InterfaceCheckout) []Rate {
       getRates(checkoutWrapper(checkoutI))
   }

   func getRates(checkoutI checkoutWrapper) []Rate {
       for _, item := range checkoutI.GetItesm() {
           p := item.GetProduct()
       }
   }

   // smaller wrapper interfaces
   type checkoutWrapper interface {
       GetItems() []InterfaceCartItem
   }
   ```

The problem I hit is that the `InterfaceCartItem` that is returned by `GetItems` has about 30 methods listed off in the interface, and I'm only using one of them `GetProduct`. So I thought I could use the same solution and create an interface with the one method I need, but when I try to change the type that is returned from `checkoutWrapper@GetItems()` golang says that `checkoutI` no longer satisfies the `checkoutWrapper` interface because it returns a different type from `GetItems` which is technically true...

Code that I tried that doesn't work

```
func GetRates(checkoutI InterfaceCheckout) []Rate {
    getRates(checkoutWrapper(checkoutI))
}

func getRates(checkoutI InterfaceCheckout) []Rate {
    for _, item := range checkoutI.GetItesm() {
        p := item.GetProduct()
    }
}

// smaller wrapper interfaces
type checkoutWrapper interface {
    GetItems() []itemWrapper
}

type itemWrapper interface {
    GetProduct() InterfaceProduct
}
```

so is interface method validation only done one level deep?

Comment: Why do you want to make `GetProduct` return an interface?

Comment: Golang's philosophy about interface is to make them small, so 30 methods is a lot. Plus, convention is to identify interfaces with -er at the end of the name : `InterfaceProduct` -> `Producter`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just embed your interface in fake objects.
For example:

```
type InterfaceCheckout interface {
    GetID() int
    GetItems() []InterfaceCartItem
}

type InterfaceCartItem interface {
    GetProduct() string
    GetID() int
}

type fakeCheckout struct {
    InterfaceCheckout
}

func (fakeCheckout) GetItems() []InterfaceCartItem {
    return []InterfaceCartItem{fakeItem{}}
}

type fakeItem struct {
    InterfaceCartItem
}

func (fakeItem) GetProduct() string {
    return "This is the end"
}

func getRates(checkoutI InterfaceCheckout) {
    for _, item := range checkoutI.GetItems() {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", item.GetProduct())
    }
}

func main() {
    fc := fakeCheckout{}
    getRates(fc)
}
```

See it in action at: https://play.golang.org/p/uSFegnZq7S

---

Side note: avoid interfaces with 30 methods, they get very cumbersome very quickly.

---

#### EDIT

> This works, but could explain why embedding the interface in the struct works

Interface embedding in structs is a little subtle. [The spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) mentions that embedding an interface will bring in its method set thus when you call methods it always compiles. It also brings in a nil member of the interface type.

```
typ := reflect.TypeOf(fc)
fmt.Printf("+%v\n", typ.Field(0))
```

You can see there's a member there:

```
{Name:InterfaceCheckout PkgPath: Type:main.InterfaceCheckout Tag: Offset:0 Index:[0] Anonymous:true}
```

How does it work at runtime?

- When you call a method that your type overrides<sup>1</sup> all is well: your method gets called
- When you call a method that you don't override, the call goes through to the embedded object which is nil. This panics much like the following would:

  ```
  var ic InterfaceCheckout // nil, just like your embedded type
  ic.GetItems()
  ```

<sub>1. A type is free to override the methods brought in by its embedded types</sub>

Comment: This works, but could explain why embedding the interface in the struct works? For example in main() if i add fc.GetID() I get a panic, I would have thought I'd get the "zero values" defined in the function's declaration

Comment: Man I am glad to see that this can be accomplished so easily though, I thought I hit an ugly edge in golang. Man I enjoy writing this language. (side note acknowledged as well)

Comment: @AKnox I added an explanation for how this is supposed to work.